# Wordpress Admins are notified by email when blog is posted or edited

Tags: wordpress, notifications, admin

I'm trying to find a way to alert all admins when a blog is posted.  My client has multiple admins setup for his Wordpress site and wants to be alerted when one of them submits a new blog post or edits one so he can double check it for spelling errors and to make sure he approves the content and he wants to be notified with an email. I searched for a plugin for this but came up empty.  Does anyone know how to do this or if their is a plugin to accomplish this that I just couldn't find?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [subscribe2 plugin](http://subscribe2.wordpress.com/). I use it on one of my membership sites to notify subscribers when something new has been posted. You can define the notification list  to include whatever email addresses you like. By default, all new posts will be emailed to those addresses.

As for edits, I don't think the plugin does it by default, however it does add a checkbox at the bottom of the post editor that allows an notification to be forced.

Answer (score 0):

For other developers, who are facing same issue, here is a pretty cool plugin. It is very light weight and easy to configure. Below is the link

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-status-notifier/